# Sync two external harddrives?

Tags: sync, external-hard-drive

A little mishap happened earlier today and i am thinking i should have a copy of my external harddrive since 10% of it is very valuable. What is the best solution to keep two external harddrive in sync? i'll probably use one as regular and maybe use the other only to copy data. The easiest way to keep it in sync is to clear one drive and copy the other but 1T of data will take a long time.

Whats a good existing app that will keep them in sync? freeware preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`rsync`](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) and maybe [`rdiff-backup`](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/).

On Windows - `robocopy` (comes with Vista).

Comment: it looks like `robocopy C:\src C:\dst /mir /copyall` will do the trick (but requires admin rights to access/set the security attr with copyall) -edit- to note mir will delete files that dont exist on src like i wanted.

Comment: There are a few more flags you might want to look at. For example /b allows you to copy directories even if you're not the owner, as long as you run robocopy as an admin. (I have a bunch of user folders -- Desktop, Documents, etc. -- from previous Windows installations on my external drives, and it's impossible to access them without either using that flag, or painfully changing the owner and permissions first.) You might also want to exclude junction points and symbolic links, which will get traversed unless you explicitly say otherwise.

Answer (score 11):

If you're in Windows, you can use [Synctoy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en). Very easy to use IMO.

Comment: I like this because it's so easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/is-freefilesync-better-sync-software-than-microsoft-synctoy-windows/) compares [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/) and [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155)

Although they roughly perform the same functions, FreeFileSync had an edge over SyncToy in
Performance, portability and overall has slightly more features.
One advantage in particular of FreeFileSync over SyncToy is the ability to copy locked (ie open) files (SyncToy can’t copy locked files)

Answer (score 0):

When I have to use Windows or when setting up for Windows users.

For hourly and daily unattended sync I really like [PtReplicator](http://www.karenware.com/powertools/ptreplicator.asp) which is a really easy, powerful, fast, and free.

When I am doing manual syncs, or have an external that I want to have the software and settings available on the external disk when I plug it in I use [Toucan Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/toucan). I love this one because I have several different drives for specific uses.

When I'm on my Ubuntu boxes I agree with the [Grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/) suggestion.